# Python 2.6.2: writing lines to file hard wrap at 192 characters

Tags: python

I implemented a function to make a wrapper to write to files.  This is the code:

```
def writeStringToFile(thestring, thefile, mode='w'):
    """Write a string to filename `thefile' to the directory specified in `dir_out'."""
    with open(os.path.join(dir_out, thefile), mode) as fh:
        fh.write("{0}\n".format(thestring))
```

I found out that when I write any string over 192 characters, a newline is inserted at character 192, resulting in a hard wrap in my output file, which I don't want.

I looked at the docs for the `open` and `write` function/method, and I don't see anything that would specify a hard wrap at any line length.

Any insight into fixing this is appreciated.

Comment: I find this very surprising. Are you sure that it's not the editor/viewer that you use to examine the output file that's wrapping long lines?

Comment: @mpettis: Now.  Please remove your comment "See my edit above, it was my own stupidity".  Please put those words into your answer -- where they belong -- and remove the comment.

Answer (score 1):

My own stupidity -- I was writing strings that had the character sequence `\n` in them, and python was rightly interpreting them as newlines.  I need to escape them in my string.  I'd take this post down if it hadn't already been responded to.

Answer (score 0):

`fh.write()` won't wrap long lines. There are two possibilities:

1. `thestring` contains an embedded newline at position 193.
2. The editor/viewer that you're using to examine the output file is wrapping long lines.

The first possibility is easy to eliminate by printing out the value of `thestring`.

The second possibility can be eliminated by looking at the output file in a hex viewer (e.g. `xxd`) to see whether the extraneous newline is in fact part of the file or is simply a display artefact.